# Where is the "foo" path in file system api?

Tags: html, api

I want to make a APP based on Chrome offline to do local file write and read.
I tried to understand how the `File System API` work.

My question is where the "foo" path really is in windows 7?

[HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#directories) is the W3's documentary about the path.

I tried the example supplied by W3, and are there any other simple examples?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: That W3 document is just showing how two directory paths are equivalent.  `foo/./bar` is equivalent to `foo/bar`.  This is true on all operating systems I've ever used.  For example, `C:\Users\.\JohnDoe` is the same as `C:\Users\JohnDoe` on win 7.  JohnDoe is fictional, kinda like foo and bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is a meta-variable, it's not an actual real thing, rather just something to use as a place-holder.

It's similar to things like `/path/to/file` which doesn't mean you need a literal hierarchy containing those directories, rather it means substitute in the real path to your file.

`foo`, `bar`, `baz` are all common, I also use `xyzzy`, `plugh` and `twisty` due to rather large amounts of my youth being wasted on text adventure games :-)

All that the W3C document is saying with a comment like:

```
Thus 'foo/./bar' is equivalent to 'foo/bar', and './foo' is equivalent to 'foo'.
```

is that `./` can be effectively removed from the path string if it's at the front or immediately following a `/`. This is true *regardless* of the actual path components you use in place of `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Thank you all. if I do this " fs.root.getFile("already_there.txt", ...); " to create a text file. Where the file should be found in my local OS?

Comment: @Amy, for that one, it should be located at the root level of the file system. Note that's the _HTML_ file system, not the hard disk. Where the HTML file systems are located on your hard disk (if at all) depends on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm newbie to HTML5, sorry for the naive question. Let me say like this, if my html file is here [ file:///C:/test.html ] and ,I just use Javascript to create a file like before, how could I open the file.

Comment: I downloaded the Google Chrome Canary which is a debug tool, then all works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` and `bar` are typically used as placeholder terms when explaining something that relies on user defined names. It is used when the name can be something arbitrary.